# Convert android socket activity into fragment

Tags: android, sockets, fragment

I was currently trying to convert android socket activity into android socket fragment. However, after export all the code into fragment method, the application always stop working when connect button pressed. Below is the code for mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static TextView textResponse;
    private EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
    private Button buttonConnect;
    private String message = "Hi client!";
    private static String kq = "";
    private ClientTask myClientTask;
    private OnListener listener;
    private static boolean flag = true;
    Socket socket = null;

    public interface OnListener {
        void listener(String text);
    }

    public void addListener(OnListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    static Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (flag) {
                kq += msg.obj.toString() + "\r\n";
                textResponse.setText(kq);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myClientTask = new ClientTask(editTextAddress.getText()
                        .toString(), Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText()
                        .toString()));
                myClientTask.execute();
            }
        });

    }

    public class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements
            OnListener {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        PrintWriter out1;


        ClientTask(String addr, int port) {
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                out1 = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                //out1.print("Hello server!");
                out1.flush();

                BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                do {
                    try {
                        if (!in1.ready()) {
                            if (message != null) {
                                MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1,
                                        "Server: " + message).sendToTarget();
                                message = "";
                            }
                        }
                        int num = in1.read();
                        message += Character.toString((char) num);
                    } catch (Exception classNot) {
                    }

                } while (!message.equals("bye"));

                try {
                    sendMessage("bye");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                if (socket.isClosed()) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lỗi nhập!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void listener(String text) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendMessage(text);
        }

        void sendMessage(String msg) {
            try {
                out1.print(msg);
                out1.flush();
                if (!msg.equals("bye"))
                    MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1, "Me: " + msg)
                            .sendToTarget();
                else
                    MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1,
                            "Ngắt kết nối!").sendToTarget();
            } catch (Exception ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void send(View v) {
        addListener(myClientTask);
        if (listener != null)
            listener.listener(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1))
                    .getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.listener("bye");
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.listener("bye");
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

And this is the code for android socket in fragment

```
public class blank extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private static TextView textResponse;
private static EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
private static Button buttonConnect;
private String message = "Hi Nice to meet you Client";
private static String kq= "";
private static boolean flag=true;
private OnListener listener;
private ClientTask myClientTask;
Socket socket = null;

public interface OnListener {
    void listener(String text);
}

public void addListener(OnListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

static Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (flag) {
            kq += msg.obj.toString() + "\r\n";
            textResponse.setText(kq);
        }
    }
};

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public blank() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static blank newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    blank fragment = new blank();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    editTextAddress = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.address);
    editTextPort = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.port);
    buttonConnect = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.connect);
    textResponse = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.response);



    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClientTask = new ClientTask(editTextAddress.getText()
                    .toString(), Integer.parseInt(editTextAddress.getText()
                    .toString()));
            myClientTask.execute();
        }
    });

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

public class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements
        OnListener {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    PrintWriter out1;

    ClientTask(String addr, int port) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            out1 = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out1.flush();

            BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()
            ));
            do {
                try {
                    if (!in1.ready()) {
                        if (message != null) {
                            blank.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1,
                                    "Server : " + message).sendToTarget();
                            message = "";
                        }
                    }
                    int num = in1.read();
                    message += Character.toString((char)num);
                }
                catch (Exception classNot) {

                }
            } while ((message.equals("bye !")));
            try {
                sendMessage("bye");
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            if (socket.isClosed()) {
                flag = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Disconnect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void listener(String text) {
        sendMessage(text);
    }

    void sendMessage(String msg) {
        try {
            out1.print(msg);
            out1.flush();
            if (!msg.equals("bye"))
                blank.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1, "Me: " + msg)
                        .sendToTarget();
            else
                blank.handler.obtainMessage(0, 0, -1,
                        "Disconnected !").sendToTarget();
        } catch (Exception ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void send(View v) {
    addListener(myClientTask);
    if (listener != null)
    {
        listener.listener(((EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1))
        .getText().toString());
    }
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.listener("bye");
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.listener("bye");
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    super.onStop();
}

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), blank.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }

}
```

The code is working well in activity but not in fragment. FYI, once the socket establishes the fragment textview will be updated and display welcome text. May I know where should I put code those code in instead of onCreateView method ?

Comment: Please do not repost the same problem within ten hours. Especially in the weekend.